# Links not clickable in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I have a angular2 component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'sidenav',
templateUrl: './sidenav.html',
styleUrls: ['./sidenav.scss'],

})
export class SidenavComponent {

constructor() {

}
}
```

I want to include it in another component, which works fine except that the links don't work:

```
 <li><a routerLink="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
```

I include the component simply with the tag

```
<sidebar> </sidebar>
```

what is the missing part. I included the router but it didn't help.

I use the generated jhipster app and want to add a sidenav only for authorized Users. There are many modules and routes defined including each other, but I just don't find the right way.

Comment: Did you add `RouterModule` to imports of the module that contains above component?

Comment: The component SidenavComponent `<jhi-sidenav></jhi-sidenav>` is included in the template of the SidebarComponent `<sidebar></sidebar>`?

Comment: can u plz share a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

> I include the component simply with the tag
>
> `<sidebar> </sidebar>`

Isn't it supposed to be `<sidenav> </sidenav>`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u r not using RouterModule correctly?

```
RouterModule.forRoot(<urRouteDataStructure>)
```

this is the setting in the imports-array.

I am sharing my code below for reference:-
(I am using bootstrap 3.x)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
```

...
   ...
    import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {    path:'server',
      component: ServerComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    BasicHighlightDirective,
    BetterHighlightDirective,
    UnlessDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [LoggingService, AccountsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <!-- <li role="presentation"><a href="/serv"> Server Comp </a> </li> -->
        <li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/server"> Server Comp </a> </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/">  Home Comp</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres my output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Plankton, i Just added a some information to my question since it is generated jhipster app

Comment: Doesnt matter, where or how it is created, if u use the above steps, it will work